# Error in viewing a product on my django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

[image: error image]

Hey guys I get this error thrown up at me when I click a product on my Django project. I assume its a spelling mistake in either my view or models but I cant see anything. I've attach both an image of the error and my code. Any help would be appreciated. apologies if my post does not contain the correct information needed I'm new to coding.

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category,Product

def allProdCat(request, category_id=None):
    c_page = None
    products = None
    if category_id != None:
        c_page = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=c_page, available=True)

    else:
        products = Product.objects.all().filter(available=True)

    return render(request,'shop/category.html',{'category':c_page, 'products':products})

def prod_detail(request,category_id,product_id):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(category_id=category_id,id=product_id)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e 
    return render(request,'shop/product.html', {'product':product})

models

import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:products_by_category', args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phoneshop:prod_detail', args=[self.category.id, self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

category.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block metadescription %}
    {% if category %}
        {{ category.description|truncatewords:155 }}
    {% else %}
        Welcome to the cushion store where you can buy comfy and awesome cushions.
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    {% if category %}
        {{ category.name }} - The Fantastic Electronic ShopnDrop
    {% else %}
        See our wide range of products including everything from phones to tablets - The Fantastic Electronic ShopnDrop
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <!--Breadcrumb navigation-->
    {% if category %}
        <div class="row my_row_class">
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <p><a href="{% url 'phoneshop:allProdCat' %}">Our Product Collection</a> | {{category.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="mx-auto">
    {% if category %}
        <img class="my_image" src="{{category.image.url}}" alt="{{category.name}}">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center my_title">{{category.name}}</h1>
        <p class="text-justify">{{category.description}}</p>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        <img class="my_image my_image_padding" src="{% static 'images/banner.jpg' %}" alt="Our Products Collection">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center my_title">Our Products Collection</h1>
        <p class="text-justify">Find a phone can be difficult at the best of times. With horrible products and prices its a nightmare
            But with our wide range of products, The Fantastic Electronic ShopnDrop, could one be the one stop shop
            for you.
        </p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mx-auto"> 
            {% for product in products %}
                <div class="my bottom margin col-9 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="cart text-center" style="min-width: 18rem;">
                        <a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}"><img class = "card-img-top my_image"><img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{product.name}}"></a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                            <p>€{{product.price}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

product.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block metadescription %}
    {{ product.description|truncatewords:155 }}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    {{ product.name }} - The Fantastic Electronic ShopnDrop
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row my_prod_row_class">
        <div class="mx-auto">
            <p><a href="{% url 'phoneshop:allProdCat' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{{ product.category.get_url }}">{{product.category}}</a> | {{product.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-ml-12 col-lg-6 text-center">
                    <div style="min-width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
                    </div>
                </div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="my_prod_title"></h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
                        <p>€{{product.price}}</p>
                        <p class="my_title">Product Description</p>
                        <p class="text-justify my_prod_text">{{product.description}}</p>
                        {% if product.stock == 0%}
                            <p class="text-justify my_prod_text"><b>Out of Stock</b></p>
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="btn btn-success">Add to Cart</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name ='phoneshop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allProdCat, name ='allProdCat'),
    path('<uuid:category_id>/', views.allProdCat, name='products_by_category'),
    path('<uuid:cateogry_id>/<uuid:product_id>/', views.prod_detail, name='prod_detail'),
]
```

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Anyway your error is most likely in a template where you write something like `{% url 'url-name-of-prod_detail' 'cateogry_id' other_arg %}`

Comment: @AaronKenny what's the use of adding the urls? I said the typo might be there, and it is there. You could have seen it yourself even... `path('<uuid:cateogry_id>/<uuid:product_id>/', views.prod_detail, name='prod_detail'),` see it? your typo `cateogry_id`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat clearly my eyes don't work as I couldn't see it. thanks